# How to store dates in json format and display them one by one for a given range?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs and I am trying to store dates in a json format and display it in a list wise manner.

Here,I want the minDate to be the date which the user gives and the maxDate to be the current date.

I want to display dates from the minDate to maxDate through a 'for' loop in which dates are incremented by 1,do we need a function to calculate the no. of days also?

---

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
        <input type="date" ng-model="min">
        <li ng-repeat="n in range(min,max)">{{dt.date | date}}</li>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('Main', function ($scope){
  $scope.max = new Date();
  $scope.date = [];
  $scope.range = function(min, max){ 
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i ++) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
        $scope.date.push({
        dt: $scope.date
         });
return date;              
}
};
```

---

**Output should be like**

```
Date 1:
07/20/2016
Date 2:
07/24/2016

Day difference = n
Day 1=20 July.2016

Day 2=21 July.2016

Day 3=22 July.2016

Day 4=23 July.2016

Day 5=24 July.2016
```

Comment: I think what you have looks good, but why are you returning `date`?  Shouldn't you be returning `$scope.date`?  Also, I think `return date;` should be outside the following curly brace because it's in the for-loop.  Another thing I noticed was that your `li` was not inside a `ul`.

Comment: you need to validate each input actually returns a date as well as return array from function.

Comment: It was just my idea of how might be the code,Can you provide me with a working fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a function in ng-repeat because it will be called with each digest cycle.  Instead, only call the function when your min date has changed.  So here's how it would look:

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('Main', function($scope) {
  $scope.min = new Date();
  $scope.max = new Date();
  $scope.dateRange = [];

  $scope.getDateRange = function() {
    $scope.dateRange = [{
      dt: angular.copy($scope.min)
    }];

    for (var thisDate = $scope.min; thisDate < $scope.max;) {
      thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + 1);

      $scope.dateRange.push({
        dt: angular.copy(thisDate)
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
  <input type="date" ng-model="min" ng-change="getDateRange()">
  <li ng-repeat="d in dateRange">{{ d.dt | date}}</li>
</div>
```

You can see it working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gg0hlv7FldNRFQz53lxJ?p=preview)

Comment: It is working fine,but it actually displays one date extra from the current date like if it's 19th july it is displaying it till 20th ?

Comment: @Vishal - you're right.  I updated my answer and the plunk with the correction.

Comment: Perfect,Thanks a lot!